# How do I parse my json into CSV using regex?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, parsing

I am trying to parse a specific string into columns in my oracle table via regular expressions and I am getting very confused by the different examples online.

This is the sample string I want to parse (this string is a single value in column called `raw string` from table `raw_string_table`):

```
Attributes : {}
Body : {
    "Type" : "TypeValue",
    "MessageId" : "MessageIDValue",
    "TopicArn" : "TopicArnValue",
    "Message" : "MessageValue",
    "Timestamp" : "TimestampValue",
    "SignatureVersion" : "SignatureVersionValue",
    "Signature" : "SignatureValue",
    "SigningCertURL" : "SigningCertURLValue",
    "UnsubscribeURL" : "UnsubscribeURLValue"
}
MD5OfBody : MD5OfBodyValue
```

(Indentation added for readability)

This is what I want my result set to be:

[image: example result set]

Comment: Looks like a bad case for regex. Why not select 2 lists from odd and even numbered items?

Comment: Looks like a set of key-value pairs. Should be matched and captured with regexes like `"key1" : "([^"]*)", "key2" : "([^"]*)"...`. Actually `Body` looks like a json object. Do you have any available parser?

Comment: Could you change the code that creates the string so it uses a more standard format like JSON? Then you can use a JSON library to parse it.

Comment: Why are you storing something like this in a database column, instead of storing all the values in their own table?

Comment: This is not JSON or I would just Convert-FromJSON in powershell. It is actually in ION format and there is no cmdlet to convert it that is why I am thinking about just loading this string to oracle and then parsing it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing is to do a regular expression for each value you're trying to extract - that way you're not dependent on ordering:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(RAW_STRING, '"Type".*:.*"(.*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS TYPE, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(RAW_STRING, '"MessageId".*:.*"(.*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS MESSAGEID,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(RAW_STRING, '"TopicArn".*:.*"(.*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS TOPICARN,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(RAW_STRING, '"Message".*:.*"(.*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS MESSAGE,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(RAW_STRING, '"Timestamp".*:.*"(.*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS TIMESTAMP,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(RAW_STRING, '"SignatureVersion".*:.*"(.*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS SIGNATUREVERSION,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(RAW_STRING, '"Signature".*:.*"(.*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS SIGNATURE,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(RAW_STRING, '"SigningCertURL".*:.*"(.*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS SIGNINGCERTURL,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(RAW_STRING, '"UnsubscribeURL".*:.*"(.*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS UNSUBSCRIBEURL
  FROM RAW_STRING_TABLE;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03f5a/13)

Best of luck.

Comment: This was the exact thing I was looking for. Thank you so much!